# KendoUI DataViz - switch between line and bar chart

Tags: jquery, charts, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-dataviz

I've got a requirement to initially show the data in a line chart and have a toggle button that will toggle between a line chart and a bar chart for the data.  Is this possible using javascript without going back to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very easy. Just set the series type and call refresh.

```
var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
chart.options.series[0].type = "line";
chart.refresh();
```

http://jsbin.com/oYUs/2/edit